# Power BI Sunburst Visualization

Tags: powerbi

Microsoft has released a custom sunburst visualization ([link](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/show/Sunburst1445472000808)) ([source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/src/Clients/CustomVisuals/visuals/sunburst/sunburst.ts)) similar to the well-known [D3.js version](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373).

I tried importing the [flare.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1093025/raw/32bbfc0fae88464c3cbda6b57bfddc4da3b5c6f4/flare.json) file used in the D3 example into Power BI, but I can't get the Power BI sunburst to display any child nodes.

Does anyone know how to make this work? Do I need to convert the JSON file into another format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Power BI,

> Get Data - Web

Paste your json url, then OK, the Edit Query box will open.
Under BI Ribbon you may see a new ribbon as

> "Convert" under which you can find "Into Table"

Here you can convert your jason file into table.

> You may need to check the results header and click them a few times to
>   get full data.

Answer (score 0):

solution

1. either you keep your Json data in javascript var where you have bind data to D3.
2. you have to load data into PBI table and then by binding you use it in power BI